# Document AI, Invoice parser how to train from code

Tags: c#, .net, gcloud, invoice, cloud-document-ai

I'm working on a task where i have to implement a way to uptrain a processor (that's already trained in gcloud) from the code. Im trying to find a solution for that but im not able to find an adequate way for trianing from code. Im curious as well what kind of information would that require from me.

I've tried looking through the official documentation but I'm not finding any good solutions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a training job by using the REST API, RPC, or Client Libraries, including C#. However, the data labeling must be done in the Cloud Console UI and the labeled documents stored in Google Cloud Storage.

Here are a few examples/documents that can help you set this up:

- [Training and evaluation overview](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/training-overview)
- [Uptrain a specialized processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/uptrain-processor)
- [`processorVersions.train` REST API](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors.processorVersions/train)
- [Python code sample for starting a training job](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/train-processor#documentai_train_processor_version-python)
- [C# Client Library Overview - Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1/latest)

  - [`TrainProcessorVersion()` Method - C#](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1.DocumentProcessorServiceClient#Google_Cloud_DocumentAI_V1_DocumentProcessorServiceClient_TrainProcessorVersion_Google_Cloud_DocumentAI_V1_TrainProcessorVersionRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_)
  - [`TrainProcessorVersionRequest` Parameters - C#](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1.TrainProcessorVersionRequest)